# What's a tool which is used by NetBeans to generate entity classes from database?

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, orm, intellij-idea

This tool can be found in Netbeans 7.2 when you press ctrl+n on and choose "Persistance -> Genarate entity classes from Database". It works great.

I'd like to use it in IntelliJ, because IntelliJ uses something diffrent (option "Generate persistnet mapping -> by database schema" from Persistance tab) to generate entities from schema. Generated classes aren't useful, because they contains only primitive types

For example:

Part of my schema:

```
create table users (
  id int not null primary key,
  login varchar(64) not null unique,
  pass char(150) not null
);

create table groups (
  login varchar(64) not null,
  group_name varchar(64) not null,
  foreign key (login) references users (login)
);
```

Part of entity generated by IntelliJ:

```
@Entity
public class Users
{

    private Integer id;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String login;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "login")
    @Basic
    public String getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login)
    {
        this.login = login;
    }

    private String pass;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "pass")
    @Basic
    public String getPass()
    {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String pass)
    {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Users users = (Users) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(users.id) : users.id != null) return false;
        if (login != null ? !login.equals(users.login) : users.login != null) return false;
        if (pass != null ? !pass.equals(users.pass) : users.pass != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (login != null ? login.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (pass != null ? pass.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Part of entity generated by NetBeans (the right way I want to use in IntelliJ)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "soccerweb", schema = "public")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findById", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLogin", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.login = :login"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPass", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.pass = :pass")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64)
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 150)
    @Column(name = "pass")
    private String pass;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Achievements> achievementsList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BlueTeam> blueTeamList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RedTeam> redTeamList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TournamentPlayers> tournamentPlayersList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Stats> statsList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TournamentStats> tournamentStatsList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TournamentAchievements> tournamentAchievementsList;
```

Comment: can't you just create them in Netbeans and then use/modify them in Intellij?

Comment: I do that. But itsn't convenient.

Comment: then it could be a nice exercise try to look for the feature in the code and see if you can extrapolate it in a reusable feature.
Since Netbeans is ant based you could also find some useful pointer in the build file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA doesn't support it yet, I've created a new feature request, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96978).

You may be also interested in the following feature requests:

- [IDEA-64709](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64709) JPA: Generate field access
- [IDEA-67051](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-67051) Create ability to reverse engineer DAO Objects via Hibernate reverse engineering

Comment: The default in IntelliJ for mapping collections is Collection, can I change the default to List or Set?  Or do I have to manually change each relationship in the Database Schema Mapping box?